# How can I access an external USB drive attached to an OS X Lion Server using FTP?

Tags: macos, ftp, osx-lion

I've just enabled FTP on a clean install of OS X Lion server, but i seem completely unable to access an external USB drive that is connected to the server using FTP. So I guess my question is:

how do I access an external USB drive that is connected to the server using FTP, from another machine on the same local network (all the machines are inside my house!).

I followed [These](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4704?viewlocale=en_US) instructions and everything seemed pretty hunky-dory. I was able to access the home folder of the user I added but I wasn't able to access anything outside of that users home folder, clearly this is fairly useless if I want to connect to a USB drive.

Am I just being dim and missing something completely obvious? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to share the volume first in `Server.app` then it can be accessed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access arbitrary files on a remote machine, `scp` (secure copy: a companion to / part of `ssh`) is often a much better choice than FTP. Is there a particular reason you must use FTP?